# select options based on another select VueJS Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using VueJs with laravel, I am new in VueJs and i want to display the Categories dynamically whenever i choose any Collection, i am sending API and using Axios, but i cant seem to figure out how to make this work.
Any help will be highly appreciated

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Collection</label>
              <select
                class="form-control"
                v-model="collection"
                @change="getCategory()"
              >
                <option
                  v-for="datas in data"
                  :key="datas.collection_name"
                  :value="datas.collection_id"
                >
                  {{ datas.collection_name }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Category</label>
              <select class="form-control" v-model="category">
                <option :value="category">
                  {{ category_name }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>


 data() {
    return {
      category_name: "",
      collection: null,
      category: null,
    };
  },



methods: {
    getCategory() {
      console.log(this.collection);
      axios
        .get("/api/products")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data[0].category_id);
          this.category = response.data[0].category_id;
          this.category_name = response.data[0].category_id;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

Controller:

```
public function create(){
$collection = Collection::join('categories','collections.id','=','categories.collection_id')
->select('categories.name as category_name','categories.id as category_id','collections.name as collection_name','collections.id as collection_id')
->get();

return response()->json($collection);

}
```

Axios response.data output is :
[image: axios response.data]

Comment: Where is your `getCategory` method defined? What is the sample data returned?

Comment: @change="getCategory()".. i have written it

Comment: Update your question to include the necessary details

Comment: I have attached the console log of reponse.data

Comment: What about the logic for your `getCategory()` method? Please see [ask].

Comment: I am struggling with the logic of it tbh, I had this in mind. But I am not able to achieve it. im not even sure if this logic is correct
 1) take Collection id from select and check in axios, 2) if collection id == category id,  3) show category id

Comment: That logic makes sense, but you are not passing any of those params to your endpoint.

Comment: How do i check in axios get if collection id == to a category id, it should loop too to show all the categories, if there is a tutorial or smntg, i would be appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I got your question very well. You want to dynamically display your categories after choosing collection data that are in laravel backend API.

in your `script` in vue js

```
data(){
        return {
            form: {
               collection:'',category: '' //define your v-models here
            },
            categories:{},
            errors: [],
        }
    },
    method:{
    getCategories(){
            axios.get('/categories/' + this.form.collection).then(response => {
                this.categories = response.data
            }).catch(errors => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors
            })
          },
    },
```

in your template now (html)

```
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">collection</label>
      <select v-model="form.collection" class="form-control" @change="getCategories()">
       <option value="">Select Collection</option>
       <option :value="collection.id" v-for="collection in collections" :key="country.id">{{ country.name }}</option>
   </select>
<div v-if="errors.collection" class="text-small text-danger"> {{ errors.collection[0] }}</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Category</label>
    <div class="form-icon position-relative">
     <select class="form-control"  v-model="form.category">
       <option value="">Select Category</option>
       <option :value="category.id" v-for=" categories" :key="city.id">{{ category.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <div v-if="errors.category" class="text-small text-danger">{{ errors.city_id[0] }}</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

you better define your v-models with form as I did above it will help you not confusing yourself. example form.collection

Comment: I did not get this part

axios.get('/categories/' + this.form.collection).then(response => {
                this.categories = response.data

Comment: that means you are get category which matches the `collection_id`, but that `collection_id` you get from v-model of `@onChange` method. I advised in question that use `form.collection` v-model so that you won't interchange the variables

Comment: Amazing, i appreciate your help

Comment: it is my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Collection</label>
            <select
                class="form-control"
                v-model="collection"
                @change="getCategory()"
                >
                <option
                    v-for="datas in data"
                    :key="datas.collection_name"
                    :value="datas.collection_id"
                    >
                    {{ datas.collection_name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="category" v-if="category_list.length > 0">
                <option v-for="(category, index) in category_list" :key="index" :value="category.id">
                    {{ category.category_name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data() {
            return {
                category: null,
                category_list: null
            };
        },

        methods: {
            getCategory() {
                axios
                    .get("/api/products")
                    .then((response) => {
                    this.category_list = response.data;
                })
                    .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It did not work, it is showing all the categories

Comment: This is what you needed as of I understand from your question. You want to show all the categories that belongs to a particular collection. If this is showing all your categories from all other collections, then blame your **API method**, not my suggestion please. I can see in your controller method, you haven't filtered the categories using `where` clause. You should return categories that belongs to the collection. And, I don't understand why you need to `join`.